# IFrame Player API in android show time in seek bar

Tags: javascript, android, youtube, youtube-api

Hello I am currently using  IFrame Player API with webView to display youtube videos

every thing is ok
but the current time and remaining time  not displayed in seek bar
I used this code

```html
<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      playerVars: {
        'playsinline': 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it it was pretty easy though
adding 0 padding& margin to the body tag then the time appeared

```
"<body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>"
```